# Component not re-rendering when using 'content' property (react-insta-stories)

Tags: reactjs, instagram-story

I am trying to create stories using `react-insta-stories`. I am using the `content` property to display the story. I am trying to change the value of a variable inside the handleclick(). here are 2 links: [link 1](https://github.com/mohitk05/react-insta-stories) [link 2](https://github.com/mohitk05/react-insta-stories/blob/162437bded3566904d175d1dd5127871e5356d0c/packages/react-insta-stories/example/src/App.js#L93). I am trying to show/hide the list of users who have viewed the story on a click function by changing the value of `showViewers`.  I can see that the component re-renders continuously until the progress of the story is over. The problem is that the component is not re-rendering when I change the value of the `showViewers` variable after the progress of the story is over.

```
{
 content: ({ action, isPaused }) => {
     const handleClick = (e) => {
         showViewers = !showViewers;
         console.log(showViewers);
     };
     return (
        <div onClick={handleClick} className={'story-wrap'}>    
        <img src={require('./img.png')} alt='' className={'story-img'}/>
        {console.log(showViewers)}      //logging value of variable
        {showViewers ? (
            <div className={'viewed-by-list-wrap'}>
                {viewedBy.map((user, index) => (
                    <div className={'viewed-by-list-item'} key={index}>
                     <img src={user.avatar} alt='' />
                        <div className={'user-name'}>
                             <p>{user.name}</p>
                            <p>{user.time}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        ) : null} 
        <div className={'see-more'} onClick={() => handleClick}>Viewed</div>
        </div>
     );
    },
    header: {
             heading: '_sudo_',
             subheading: 'Posted 32m ago',
             profileImage: require('./img.png') }
}
```

Once the progress is over and the component stops rendering, the function is called and the value of the variable is changed but the above component is not rendering.

I tried keeping the `showViwers` inside the state of the component. But then the story progress is updated from the beginning every time the state is updated.

Is there any other logic to do this feature?

Comment: please post complete code of this component

Comment: Is `showViewers `  state  ? Only when you change value of state ,  component will re render. like `this.setState({showViewers : !this.state.showViewers})`

Comment: I have edited the question with more code. Pleasse have a look.

Comment: @Kais I have tried it. But the same issue persists. Also the story progress is also  updated since the component rerenders. ie. the story is dispayyed from the beginning when  I state is updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onClick={handleClick} className={'story-wrap'}>    
        <img src={require('./img.png')} alt='' className={'story-img'}/>
        {console.log(showViewers)}      //logging value of variable
        {showViewers ? (
            <div className={'viewed-by-list-wrap'}>
                {viewedBy.map((user, index) => (
                    <div className={'viewed-by-list-item'} key={index}>
                     <img src={user.avatar} alt='' />
                        <div className={'user-name'}>
                             <p>{user.name}</p>
                            <p>{user.time}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        ) : null} 
        <div className={'see-more'} onClick={() => handleClick}>Viewed</div>
        </div>
```

your onClick handler is not working put high value of z-index in the outer div i.e in your case story-wrap.

```
.story-wrap{
  z-index: 100000;
}
```